# Compressing redundant file data

Tags: compression

I have a huge ASCII file:

```
235M Apr 16 06:50 file
```

I did the below steps:

```
cat file > file_all

cat file >> file_all

470M Apr 16 06:51 file_all
```

The size of file_1_2 is 2 * size of file_1 = 470

I used zip compression command to compress file_1 and file_all:

```
25M Apr 16 06:08 file_all.gz

49M Apr 16 06:25 file_all.gz
```

Per my understand, the compressing algorithm has below concept:

> ZIP compression is based on repetitive patterns in the data to be
>   compressed, and the compression gets better the longer the file is, as
>   more and longer patterns can be found and used.

**Question**

Why i can't take advantage of repetitions ?
Is the 1 Mega the only benefit ?

P.S: I did the same procedure with bz2 and the same note [The difference is only the compressed size itself]
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is indeed the expected outcome.

It is true that the zip compression algorithm depends on finding repeated sequences in the input. However, finding *all* repetitions would be computationally expensive, both in memory and storage. Maintaining enough information to detect a repetition of a quarter of a gigabyte would be prohibitively expensive and no compressor that I know of even comes close to this size.

Instead, compressors look for repetitions within a sliding window of limited size. In the case of zip (and gzip) this can be configured with a command-line parameter but the largest window is much less than a megabyte. (Highly repetitive inputs, such as files only containing zeros, can be compressed more because the repeated sequences can be compressed in the window itself. But in general, this won't help with long repeated sequences.)

Bzip2 uses a different strategy, but it, too, needs to limit the size of analysed input to avoid excessive runtime. As explained in the [bzip2 manual](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html#memory-management), bzip2 breaks the input into chunks and works on each chunk independently. The default (and maximum) chunk size is 900,000 bytes, which will not allow it to take advantage of multi-megabyte repeated sequences.

Comment: Thank you so much fro explanation. It it helpful.
Do you have any idea take advantage of repetition in huge files ?
Is there any mechanism ?
Also, I read about some algorithms that join a collection of files into a single object which is then compressed has the potential to detect redundancy both within and across files.

Comment: @anati: that would be the `tar` utility, which can indeed take advantage of redundancy between files, but under the same circumstances as I describe: when the redundancy can be detected within the sliding window. That usually works reasonably well. If you want to compress 235MB repetitions, you'll have to build your own tool, I'm afraid.

Comment: For example, you could use a shell script which decompresses a gzip-compression of the file twice. In short, if you know something about the data to be compressed, you can often do better than a general-purpose compression function.

Comment: This is the point.
The data in file has standard format. I think i should dig into compression in order to do customized algorithm that works well for my data.
But the overview here and your tips help me a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: 7z allows for window sizes as large as 1 GB. E.g. the option `-md=256m` would be a large enough window size to catch the duplication in the OP's question.

Comment: @MarkAdler: 7z is not installed in server that i'm working on and i don't have permission fro download.

It seems that you are expert in this field, Do you have any idea if bzip or gz have such option(for window size) ? And what is the bad side of using this option ?
Thanks

Comment: No. 7z (and the underlying LZMA) is the only generally available compressor that I know of that can have a lookback that large.

Answer (score 1):

Compressors with long-range lookback used to be restricted to 7z (like Adler mentioned) and less known ones like lrzip. But with zstd becoming mainstream, a typical installation might happen to have the capability too.

To emulate your big ASCII file I used the [enwik8](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata.html) data. I ran the following commands:

```
cat enwik8 enwik8 > enwik82
zstd enwik8
zstd enwik82
zstd --long enwik8 -o enwik8.long.zst
zstd --long enwik82 -o enwik82.long.zst
```

And the file sizes are:

```
100000000   enwik8
35633676    enwik8.long.zst
36445475    enwik8.zip
35626935    enwik8.zst
200000000   enwik82
35644486    enwik82.long.zst
71251491    enwik82.zst
```

So long range matching worked! (Do note that the default `--long` window size is 128 M, and you need to ask for `--long=28` for a 256 M window.)

Some timing information:

```
$ time zstd --long enwik82 -f -o enwik82.long.zst
enwik82              : 17.82%   (200000000 => 35644486 bytes, enwik82.long.zst) 

real    0m0.911s
user    0m0.898s
sys 0m0.130s

$ time zstd enwik82 -f -o enwik82.zst
enwik82              : 35.63%   (200000000 => 71251491 bytes, enwik82.zst)     

real    0m1.208s
user    0m1.207s
sys 0m0.162s
```

Long range matching apparently makes it faster too. The manual says it works okay with multi-threading, but I am too lazy to test right now.